# How do I control the frequency of labels on LineDataSet?

Tags: mpandroidchart

In MPAndroidChart, I can control the frequency of xaxis values with setSkipLabels.  However, this only affects the xaxis.  How do I do the same with the lines themselves in a line chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the library provide a neat way to do this for LineDataSet as for X axis.
The best bet IMHO should be to use a [custom ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) to set text to blank as required.

Exemple to show one label out of ten:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        String output = "";
        if (entry.getXIndex() % 10 == 0) output = mFormat.format(value);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Then, attach your formatter to your DataSet

```
lineDataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

This will only affect text displayed next to each value in the graph.

You could also disable drawing the circle on each value with :

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
```

Comment: Maybe once work calms down I'll do a PR for this.  We're very grateful for the lib.